# What does cannot Implicitly convert mean?

Tags: c#

```
public List<Clubs> ClubById (string clubId)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"StarTEDServices: ClubById(); clubId = {clubId}");

    return Context.Clubs
        .Where(x => x.ClubId.Equals(clubId))
        .FirstOrDefault();
}
```

This is the Error I receive:

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'StarTED.Entities.Clubs' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<StarTED.Entities.Clubs>' [StarTEDApp]csharp(CS0029)

Comment: Clubs and List<Clubs> are not the same. One is a single object, the other is a collection of objects. The language won't just let you treat one as if it's the other, because they're not the same thing. Your method signature says it returns a List<Clubs> but thanks to your FirstOrDefault() statement, only one Clubs is returned. So you either need to change the signature to be Clubs instead of List<Clubs>, or change what you're returning to not use .FirstOrDefault() and instead use .ToList(). Judging by the method name, I'd say changing the signature makes more sense.

Comment: either change your return type to `Clubs` or return a new `List<Clubs>` populated with your FirstOrDefault result or change `.FirstOrDefault()` to `.ToList()`

Comment: Thank you Very Much. I did put ToList before and removed FirstOrDefault. The errors disappeared then. The return code was what I was given and told to use. But it just does not seem to work. Way over my head. Thank you for the help.

Comment: This isn't "way over your head". A collection of objects is not the same thing as a single instance of an object. That's all this boils down to.

Comment: @KevinPerry - if you were told to use FirstOrDefault() then you may want to follow-up with the person who told you that. Changing the return type from `List<Clubs>` to `Clubs` may be more appropriate if you *really want* to return a single item (or null)

Comment: Do not name classes in the plural

Comment: In the other returns, I was given to use they were all missing ToList. So when I added ToList to correct errors they all disappeared. Except for this one. Chunks of code that I have been given seem to have pieces missing in all of it. But its hard to reach the individual for clarification

Comment: @KevinPerry What drives the decision to use List<Clubs> vs Clubs is pretty simple: will you ever have more than one Clubs (Caius is right, don't name your class as if it's plural!) instance returned as the result of your database query? Don't all the Clubs have a unique ID? Then this method should return a single Clubs (or Club, had you named the class properly). However if the query would return multiple, perhaps multiple Clubs share the same ID, then having it return a List<Club> makes sense (though that likely means your database design is poor).

Comment: *So when I added ToList to correct errors* - this isn't how we engineer software. It's not just about jiggling stuff around until compiler errors go away, because code that is syntactically correct isn't necessarily semantically correct.. Think about what you need this method to *actually do*. To my mind a method called `GetClubById` should take an int/guid (probably) ID and return a single club. It would be an odd system that had multiple clubs for a single id, because an ID normally uniquely identifies an object. Compare `GetClubsByCityId` for example..

Answer (score 2):

It means that there is no implicit conversion from `Clubs` to `List<Clubs>`.

The problem in your code is that you are telling the method that you will return a `List<Clubs>`, but in fact you are returning a single `Clubs` instead (because of the `FirstOrDefault` call).

In order to fix the error, you have 2 choices:

1. (**The likely choice you want**) Replace the return type of the method to return a single `Clubs`:

```cs
public Clubs ClubById (string clubId)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"StarTEDServices: ClubById(); clubId = {clubId}");

    return Context.Clubs
        .Where(x => x.ClubId.Equals(clubId))
        .FirstOrDefault();
}
```

2. Replace the `FirstOrDefault()` call with a `ToList()` call, in order to return a `List<Clubs>`.

```cs
public List<Clubs> ClubById (string clubId)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"StarTEDServices: ClubById(); clubId = {clubId}");

    return Context.Clubs
        .Where(x => x.ClubId.Equals(clubId))
        .ToList();
}
```